# IBM Watson Visual Recognition in Powershell

Tags: powershell, curl, watson

I am attempting to integrate Watson Visual Recognition into a powershell script, I have my free account set up and everything works form curl in a docker container.  But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to work from Powershell.

The example curl command is

```
curl "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&url=https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/visual-recognition/fruitbowl.jpg&version=2016-05-20"
```

where `{api-key}` is replaced with an actual api key

As this is just hitting a URL I expected I should be able to use

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key={api-key}&url=https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/visual-recognition/fruitbowl.jpg&version=2016-05-20"
```

However `Invoke-RestMethod` returns

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-r ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

What am I missing in my `Invoke-RestMethod` commands?  Do I need to specify some sort of headers or something?

Documentation link https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/visual-recognition/api/v3/curl.html?curl#data-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default PowerShell uses TLS 1.0 when you use Invoke-WebRequest/RestMethod and that's probably why you're not able to establish a secure connection. Ergo, the site doesn't support TLS 1.0.

Try adding the below to the top of your script to enforce TLS 1.2.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: That did it! Figures it was something dumb like that for how long I banged my head against that problem.